# Comparing MySql variables

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a addition to my website where admins can ban people, but my code isn't working. I have looked everywhere but i can't find a fix. Can anyone help me? Here is my code.

```
<?php

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("users", $con);
    $objGet = mysql_query("SELECT `blocked`  FROM `users` WHERE `username` LIKE '$username'");

    if (mysql_num_rows($objGet) === "1") {
        echo '<script>alert("Account Suspended")</script>';
        header('Location: userAccount.php?logoutSubmit=1');
    } else {
        //Do Nothing
    }
    ?>
```

Error :

> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 50

Ok i got the code working with completely modified code but it works

Comment: Please add your code in the question

Comment: Why you had commented that escape query?
It was fine.
Do work with it.

Comment: @Swellar Edited.

Comment: No it wasn't working

Comment: Any error appearing?

Comment: Nope no errors are showing

Comment: Try to echo "SELECT `blocked`  FROM `users` WHERE `username` LIKE '$username'" and put it right into mysql through phpmyadmin or so and see if there are no errors in the select.

Comment: It worked through phpmyadmin

Comment: It isn't the MySql it is the variable comparing

Comment: Ok now try to var_dump mysql_num_rows($objGet); and see what you get there. Also did the select return just one row?

Comment: It did return one row, yes

Comment: And what did var_dump return?

Comment: var_dump returned NULL

Comment: I realize that is an error so i will try to fix that

Comment: In order to pinpoint the error try this line of code : mysql_query("SELECT `blocked`  FROM `users` WHERE `username` LIKE '$username'") or die(mysql_error()); It should help

Comment: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 50

Comment: That is the error

Comment: If your semantics are correct, your goal is to notify the user if they have the `blocked` flag set. Your current query returns a row regardless of the value of the `blocked` column, as long as the `username` is a match.

Comment: @Connor ofcourse you get that error because $objGet returns false. Thats why i told you to use that line where you add die(mysql_error()). It will show you which part of query creates the error. Try just this : mysql_query("SELECT blocked FROM users WHERE username LIKE '$username'") or die(mysql_error()); instead of $objGet = mysql_query("SELECT `blocked`  FROM `users` WHERE `username` LIKE '$username'");

Comment: No errors show up with that

Comment: @Connor Wow that seems really weird. Try something like this if (!$objGet)
{
die('Something went wrong: ' . mysql_error());
} And if that does nothing, then try to put it inside try catch.

Comment: Nope nothing coming up with that either @Redrif

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with this line:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($objGet) === "1") {
```

`mysql_num_rows()` returns an integer, but you're comparing it against a string with the identity check `===`, which will always return `false`.

Maybe this would be a better comparison:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($objGet) > 0) {
```